# I need to get count of query. Do i need to write another SQL query

Tags: c#, sql

```
  public void KT1_Sprint3_GetGroupList()
    {
        string Query = 
                "SELECT name,alias,emailAdd FROM dbo.UserAccountDetailsList ua
                 WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN dbo.UserTestType ut WITH (NOLOCK) ON
                 ua.UserTestTypeId = ut.UserTestTypeID WHERE ut.Code in 
                 ('Distribution','TestGroup') and ua.IsActive = 1";

        SQlOperation(Query);

        ??????
    }
```

I need to get count of query. Do i need to write another SQL query ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `count` in your query

```
select count(*) as row_count
from your_table ua
where ua.IsActive = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the number of rows returned ?  when you loop the ResultSet you can increment a counter in your code.

for another query approach:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table AS ua WHERE ua.IsActive=1`

Comment: by first query i am getting 3 column value, then i need count of that. SELECT name,alias,emailAdd
 FROM dbo.UserAccountDetailsList ua WITH (NOLOCK) 
 INNER JOIN dbo.UserTestType ut WITH (NOLOCK) ON ua.UserTestTypeId = ut.UserTestTypeID
WHERE ut.Code in ('Distribution','TestGroup') and ua.IsActive = 1

Comment: I am doing a Unit test method in C#, which perform this SQl OPERATION AND CHECKING with assert that row returned should not be 0

Comment: Check your unit test framework for SQL assistance and boilerplate methods for checking row counts and such.  I know my unit testing environment here has this (my here language is not c#)

Answer (score 0):

This query would give you row count + required rows.

```
SELECT ua.COL_NAME,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table) as count
FROM your_table ua
WHERE ua.IsActive = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change ur SQL statement as follow:

```
SELECT Name, 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table) AS count
FROM Table WHERE Status='URGENT';
```

Then you would have the count too. But why would you want this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be executing Query before you need the count, just check the Count of the rows in the returned DataTable. If you want to do a separate query for the count, then one way to do this without repeating all of the SQL logic in Query would be:

```
string CountQuery = @"
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM
    (
        {0}
    ) x
".Format(Query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you encapsulated the actual SQL call.

```
SQlOperation(Query);
```

We can't really tell what you used.

If you used a datatable, it's in

```
dt.rows.count();
```

If you are using a datareader, you count it yourself when you loop through the records.

I assume that your intention is not to make a separate call for the counts.